# How to check if clicked on UI object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and trying to make a basic minesweeper game. I have a square prefab and I want to learn if it is clicked. But I can not do it listening because I need both left click and right click. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute quickest way should be to implement something like this on the prefab you wish to listen for clicks on:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseDown(0)) {
         // Left click
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseDown(1)) {
        // Right click
    }

}
```

If you instead want to detect mouseclicks from a more central position (as in, not distributed to each GameObject) you will need to create a component that fires Raycasts depending on left & right-clicks and look for specific objects, and then do you logic

Short example:

```
if (Input.GetMouseDown(0)) {

    if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100)) {
        // something was hit
    }

}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Maybe the problem is that they are in a grid and they are widgets?

Answer (score 0):

You can try usign the `Input.GetKeyDown` function in the `Update`:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            //print("Right click");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            //print("Left click");
        }
    }
```

For detecting if the mouse is over the spesific game object you can use:

```
void OnMouseOver()
     {
         ///
     }
```

Or

```
Ray ray;
     RaycastHit hit;

     void Update()
     {
         ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
         {
             print (hit.collider.name);
         }
     }
```

Comment: But when I use this, it calls every clone, how can I check if it is the pressed clone?

Comment: I don't know why but it does not call OnMouseOver when I create a method named so

Comment: See the documentation to see that you need to have for it to work (mose of the time it's `rigidbody` , `mesh` and `collider`.